# Detect key press by physical key position?

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there any way to detect the keyboard press by position? Say detect whether the bottom left letter key (In my case, "z" on a qwerty keyboard) has been pressed.

I am asking this question due to the difference in the letters in certain keys of different keyboards. For example, the letter "y" in a qwerty keyboard is in a different position of the letter "y" in a qwertz keyboard or that of a dvorak keyboard.

I am wondering if there is any way to detect whether a user presses a certain position on a keyboard so as to make sure that the layout of the keyboard (dvorak, qwerty, etc.) does not affect the controls. An example is the WASD controls for games on a keyboard. If the keyboard layout is in DVORAK, the WASD controls will not work.

Is there any way (By code or by Modules) to detect a keypress on a certain physical position of a key on python? like the top left letter key. (Preferably on Windows)